# How can I wait to see how many times the light flashes with arduino?

Tags: c++, arduino, microcontroller

I know this may seem like a random question, basically I have a photo resistor set up in a circuit so that it detects light . I have a laser that will flash for different amounts of time to signal something, lets say a flash of 1/2 a second followed by a flash of 1 second = a.

How can I wait and detect this, sorry if this doesn't make sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function will return the amount of time a laser module was shot at a photo resistor in milliseconds:

```
int photo_resistor_time()
{
    int i = 0;
    while (photo_resistor_value > 100)
    {
        i++;
        Delay(1);
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, This is really all I needed, my  mind went completely blank!

Comment: Could you please argue in favour of your solution? What is the need of having`i` when *Arduino* has two very comfortable functions `millis()` and `micros()` to keep track of time and compute *"precise"* delta time ? Your approach is subject to *clock drifting*, and depending on real case scenario it might result in *a significant error* being accumulated

Comment: @PatrickTrentin I am not used to the Arduino's IDE, I am mainly C++ devloper. But this function will generate the same output regardless. If there are other functions that could be done, then yes OP should use it. I was only trying to put my C++ knowlege to help OP out

Comment: Sure, for a couple of seconds then it might very well be that is good enough, that's why i didn't downvote your solution. But since clock drifting is a real world issue I thought i might as well mention it, before anyone jumps here and starts using this solution for bigger intervals of time. :)